# Jeditable doesnt update new input data on loaded ajax page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jeditable

im using Jeditable extension on ajax loaded content. When Im using static content, there is no problem with updating new input data. But in ajax loaded content, it doesnt replace old data with new data. What is the problem here?

Im using these Jquery plugins on same page:

1. [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)
2. [Ajax Pagination](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/10/pagination-with-jquery-php-ajax-and.html)

In ajax.php

```
                    $(function() {
                    $(".gsmDegistir").editable("'.$yazilimurl.'?sayfa=ajax;stil=smsRehber;islem=gsmDegistir", {
                        indicator : \'<img src="'.$resimurl.'/site/ajax-loader.gif">\',
                        tooltip : "'.T_('Düzenlemek için çift tıklayın...').'",
                        event : "dblclick",
                        style : "inherit",
                        cancel : "İptal",
                        submit : "OK",
                        placeholder : "",
                        id   : "trid",
                        name : "yeniGsm"
                    });});
```

In page.php

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    function loading_show()
                {
                    $("#icerikYukleniyor").css("display","block");
                }

                function loading_hide()
                {
                    $("#icerikYukleniyor").css("display","none");
                }

                function loadData(page)
                {
                    loading_show();
                    var rgid = $("select#grupSec").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "'.$yazilimurl.'?sayfa=ajax;stil=smsRehber;islem=rehberListesi",
                        data: "p=" + page + "&rgid=" + rgid,
                        success: function(veri) {
                            $("#rehberTelefonListe").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                loading_hide();
                                $("#rehberTelefonListe").html(veri);
                            });
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            $("#rehberTelefonListe").html("'.T_('Bağlantı sorunu oluştu.').'");
                        }
                    });
                }

                loadData(1); // For first time page load default results
                $("#rehberTelefonListe .pagination li.active").live("click",function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr("p");
                    loadData(page);
                });
            });});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for ajax loaded pages.

Sounds like what I need

```
$('#go1').live('click', function() {});
```

`$.fn.live`, as event handlers are only registered on initial DOM creation, and you're repopulating the DOM and those aren't attached.

More info @ http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live